# Factorizing $X^4-Y^2$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I want to factorize $X^4-Y^2$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$ in irreducible factors.

I thought about using Eisenstein's criterium to show that it is irreducible, though I'm not sure what the prime element is in this case. What would that be?

Comment: Have you thought about the difference of squares?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$X^4-Y^2=(X^2-Y)(X^2+Y)$ is the factorization

Comment: Great! It remains to show that $X^2\pm Y$ are irreducible.